# Jenkinsfile First run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I never tried Jenkinsfile before, but here's the issue.
When I run examples from online, it seems like it's hanging. The message from console output is as below:

```
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
Waiting for next available executor
```

The code I am trying to run is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

/**
 * Sample Jenkinsfile for Jenkins2 Pipeline
 * from https://github.com/hotwilson/jenkins2/edit/master/Jenkinsfile
 * by wilsonmar@gmail.com
 */

import hudson.model.*
import hudson.EnvVars
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import java.net.URL

try {
  node {
    stage '\u2776 Stage 1'
    echo "\u2600 BUILD_URL=${env.BUILD_URL}"

    def workspace = pwd()
    echo "\u2600 workspace=${workspace}"

    stage '\u2777 Stage 2'
  } // node
} catch (exc) {
  /*
   err = caughtError
   currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
   String recipient = 'infra@lists.jenkins-ci.org'
   mail subject: "${env.JOB_NAME} (${env.BUILD_NUMBER}) failed",
           body: "It appears that ${env.BUILD_URL} is failing, somebody should do something about that",
             to: recipient,
        replyTo: recipient,
   from: 'noreply@ci.jenkins.io'
  */
} finally {

  (currentBuild.result != "ABORTED") && node("master") {
    // Send e-mail notifications for failed or unstable builds.
    // currentBuild.result must be non-null for this step to work.
    step([$class: 'Mailer',
      notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true,
      recipients: "${email_to}",
      sendToIndividuals: true
    ])
  }

  // Must re-throw exception to propagate error:
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Thank you

Comment: From this it looks an awful lot like your Jenkins server isn't configured with an Executor, or there are none available - which could be because they're all runnning, or you have some kind of limitation on their availability so the wildcard (`node` without a label) node workspace isn't able to get one.

Comment: Oh, and try removing your `try/catch/finally` - not sure where you're getting the `err` in `if (err)` in your `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

the error state that there are not left in your node (master i assume)
go to --> Manage Jenkins --> Manage Nodes and Clouds --> enter your node --> Configure --> increase # of executors